# App crashing on applying style to TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am getting below error when I am using style in TextInputLayout. How can I fix this?

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this
> component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a
> descendant).

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxStrokeColor="#ffcc00"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Applying this fixes the issue but outline border is not achieved in TextInputLayout

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You have to use a Theme.MaterialComponents in your app theme , not as android:theme in your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your Application theme isn't material theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        ...
 </style>
```

For example it's like code above. So change it to Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar

But if you don't want change hole theme of your app you may add code below to your layout's root ViewGroup

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge">
        
        ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```